# Problem in Initialization of PICAN2 on RPi3

Tags: raspi-config, can-bus

I'm trying to initialize my PICAN 2 on a RPi3. I have installed the Kernel 4.4.9-V7+ and after `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I have edited /boot/config.txt by adding the following lines:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=25
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835-overlay
```

Above lines are exactly what the producer of PICAN2 (SK Pang electronics) suggests for initialization of this kernel. 
However, when I run the following command (after reboot):

```
sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
```

It shows the following error:

```
Cannot find device "can0"
```

I looked into the following page:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=155651&p=1165676#p1165676

Based on it, I removed -overlay; nothing changed.
I'm a beginner in Linux. So, is there something that I need to configure and I don't know?

One more maybe stupid question: I'm testing the software while PiCAN2 is not mounted on the RPi3; is this correct? or I must connect the network during initialization?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue on my Pi3 with the PiCAN2 device.

I found this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1c5QhnjTmE&t=287s) and following their instructions, my PiCAN2 was visible to Raspbian as "can0".

To summarize, I removed -overlay from both lines in the boot config file and modified the interrupt request pins.